# Expanding out list comprehension (to understand it better)?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, list-comprehension

I'm looking at some code and trying to figure out how to parse the list comprehension to better understand it.
The full length of code to run it, etc. is rather long, but I thought I could just try to show how I'm trying to "break it down" into more lines of code to understand it better.

example 1:

```
for currentIter in trainEx:
    temp = {key: weights[key] + 0.05 * currentF[key]*currentT[1] if key in weights else 0.05*currentF[key]*currentT[1] for key in currentF.keys()}
```

Again, I'm not totally sure how to "break down" what temp equals into all the bits and pieces.
I tried this, but I know it is incorrect:

```
for currentIter in trainEx:
    if key in weights:
        temp = {key: weights[key] + 0.05 * currentF[key]*currentT[1]}
    else:
        for key in currentF.keys():
        temp = {key: 0.05*currentF[key]*currentT[1]}
```

example 2:

```
pi = {weights.keys()[i] : random.randint(1, 100) for i in range(len(weights.keys())) if random.randint(0,1) == 1}
```

Again, I am having some trouble breaking this down, possibly because of the set notation.

Unfortunately all of these examples are part of a very long piece of code I'm trying to comprehend.
I can provide it (but it's very long/multiple files) if that helps.
However, I think most of this is just trying to break down the one line of code using list comprehension into multiple lines, just to get a better idea of what it is doing.
Any help would be appreciated to see where I'm going wrong.

Edit: I removed the examples I solved and left the others up.

Comment: You are right, your expansion of the list comprehension in the first example is not the same. In the list comprehension `myList` gets updated in each iteration of the for loop and will only contain examples whose assignments match the current iteration (which is strange itself). Your double for loop however will fill `myList` with ANY examples whose assignment has a match for ANY value in the range of x. Not sure if this helps, but before diving too much into the python make sure you understand the goal of this code at a higher level.

Comment: Yes I just caught that/understand that one. Do you have any idea on the other two?

Comment: You should place some parentheses within the ternary in the last block

Comment: `for key in myNumber` is not iterating anything. Your second example therefore has an empty dictionary in both cases

Answer (score 1):

First, try running some sample code to see if you get the same results.

One thing to note, you're overriding the lists/dictionaries each time you perform the outer loop. Depending on the rest of the code, that might not be the intent.

As for the more complex one, start with something like this

```
temp = dict()
for currentIter in trainEx:
    for key in currentF.keys():
        temp[key] = (weights[key] + 0.05 * currentF[key]*currentT[1]) if (key in weights) else (0.05*currentF[key]*currentT[1])
```

Then extract the conditional

```
temp = dict()
for currentIter in trainEx:
    for key in currentF.keys():
        if key in weights:
            temp[key] = weights[key] + 0.05 * currentF[key]*currentT[1]
        else:
            temp[key]  = 0.05*currentF[key]*currentT[1]
```

And for the last one, its similar, but you don't need the `range()`

```
pi = dict()
for k in weights.keys():
    if random.randint(0,1) == 1:
        pi[k] = random.randint(1, 100)
```

Comment: you should show where `temp` is getting defined (and how)

Comment: temp is not being defined as a set here is it?

Comment: @J.P. It never was a set, it's a `dict()`